# touchscreen broken, how to enter encryption password via adb

Tags: adb, twrp, encryption

My touch screen is insensitive in some parts, and my phone is encrypted, and one of the keys needed for the password cannot be entered.

I have TWRP installed. I remember having entered the password via adb, so there must be a way, but I don't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I found it out now:

```
adb shell twrp decrypt $PASSWORD
```